# input() causing "EOL while scanning string literal" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, syntax

I'm currently trying to write a block in Python 3.4.7 that runs if the inputted material is <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it displays the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Some example code:

```
answer = input("to find out your result, press enter.")
# Problem is here, I don't know what kind of sign or Python rule I'm not following
while answer == (<<Enter>>):
    print("You are the father!")
```

Comment: The call to `input` **doesn't end** until you press Enter. All you need is `answer = input(...); print(...)`. `while answer == (<<Enter>>):` makes **literally no sense**.

Comment: Including the error, rather than just saying "something like an EOL scanning literal" would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `raw_input` when expecting strings as input. `input` evaluates as a python expression.

Comment: That's only for Python 2. The question title specifies that this is Python 3.

Comment: @sweeneyrod the question title specifies (specified) Python 3.4 **.7** which doesn't exist (3.4.3 comes out in about a week). I think the asker doesn't know what version he's using.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that `while answer == (<<Enter>>)` means anything in Python? I would recommend doing a Python tutorial so you can get the hang of the syntax.

If I understand what you want, you can just delete that line:

```
answer = input("to find out your result, press enter.")
print("You are the father!")
```

The call to `input` stops anything else happening until enter is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're not actually using Python 3 (unless you're from the year 2017, when I'd guess Python 3.4.7 might be released). The input to `input()` in Python 2 gets executed (`input(prompt)` = `eval(raw_input(prompt))`), and when it's just an empty string, it causes a `SyntaxError`:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input('Hello?')
Hello?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Using `raw_input()` is usually what you want. The old `input()` was removed in Python 3 and old `raw_input()` took it's place.

Comment: I am from the year 2017 ;)